# span<T> and streams

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard-2.0

I have been reading about span for a while now, and just tried to implement it. However, while I can get span to work I cannot figure out how to get a stream to accept it like they do in the examples. Other examples show int.parse supporting spans as well but I can't find overloads or extensions that make it possible.

I have tried it in both `.net standard 2.0` and `.net core 2.0`

Please point me in the right direction to make this work.

**Code example**

```
Span<Byte> buffer = new Span<byte>();
int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer);
```

Comment: Um could you be more specific? But if you're talking about reading from a stream, try this `reader.ReadBlock(charArray, 0, span.Length);`

Comment: Can you edit and post some code so we can understand what you need?

Comment: No, I am talking about using the new span<T> class to read from a stream. It is different from your typical byte array or text classes.

Comment: @Denise the question is about *spans* not blocks. This is a perfectly valid question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Span results from streams are supported in .NET Core 2.1. If you check the current source code of eg [Stream](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/Stream.cs#L724) you'll see it has overloads like [Read(Span)](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/Stream.cs#L724) that read into a `Span<byte>` instead of `byte[]`, or [Write(ReadOnlySpan)](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/Stream.cs#L757) that can write out a `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` instead of a `byte[]`, overloads that use Memory etc.

To target .NET Core 2.1, you'll have to install at least [Visual Studio 2017 15.7 Preview 4](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/04/18/visual-studio-2017-15-7-preview-4/) or the [latest SDK for .NET Core 2.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/04/11/announcing-net-core-2-1-preview-2/)

Comment: I thought it would be something like that. I was just unable to find the links on any of the websites. Thanks for your help. I will probably just wait until it gets out of preview.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesWoods you don't have to. 2.1 installs side-by-side and you get to choose which runtime version to use when you create a new project. Plus, MS Build is just around the corner. There may be some interesting announcements next week

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What happens when you close and dispose of the stream? Will the `Span<T>` point into the void?

Comment: @silkfire the method use spans provided by the caller. They'll exist for as long as the caller needs them.

Answer (score 6):

Let's look at an example that I have handy, where the `Span<T>` happens to come from `PipeWriter`.

```
var bufferSpan = pipeWriter.GetSpan(count);
stream.Write( /* Darn, I need an array, because no Span<T> overloads outside Core 2.1! */ );
```

Try to get a `Memory<T>` instead of `Span<T>`, for which you can get the underlying array (except under some exotic circumstances).

```
var bufferMemory = pipeWriter.GetMemory(count); // Instead of GetSpan()
var bufferArraySegment = bufferMemory.GetUnderlyingArray();
stream.Write(bufferArraySegment.Array, bufferArraySegment.Offset, bufferArraySegment.Count); // Yay!
```

`GetUnderlyingArray()` here is a small extension method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Memory extensions for framework versions that do not support the new Memory overloads on various framework methods.
/// </summary>
internal static class MemoryExtensions
{
    public static ArraySegment<byte> GetUnderlyingArray(this Memory<byte> bytes) => GetUnderlyingArray((ReadOnlyMemory<byte>)bytes);
    public static ArraySegment<byte> GetUnderlyingArray(this ReadOnlyMemory<byte> bytes)
    {
        if (!MemoryMarshal.TryGetArray(bytes, out var arraySegment)) throw new NotSupportedException("This Memory does not support exposing the underlying array.");
        return arraySegment;
    }
}
```

All in all, this lets you use the methods with a 'modern' return type in combination with the 'old' framework overloads - without any copying. :)

Comment: This only works for read-only memory. The truth is that `Stream` API is quite broken: `byte[]` is not a substitute for "a chunk of memory". Internally, the `Read(Span<T>)` copies via an intermediate array.

Comment: @KubaOber I think you could never have a `Stream` based on a `(ReadOnly)Span<byte>`. Spans are stack-only types, and streams are not. The stream could outlive the span. `Stream` in its current form could be based on `(ReadOnly)Memory<byte>` at best. You'd need a stack-only stream if you wanted to wrap a span.

Comment: Of course Span and Memory go hand-in-hand, and both should be supported (supporting one must imply supporting other, otherwise it's a broken API).

Comment: Actually I see that I've been mixing things up. The question itself was about reading from a stream into a span, which either requires .NET Core 2.1+, or that you pass your own array and afterwards you get a span over that array (which is probably not what OP was looking for). My answer, I now realize, addresses _writing_ to the stream _from_ a `Memory<byte>`, in the absence of the Core 2.1 overloads that accept a span. Thirdly, there is the case of constructing a stream over a `Memory<byte>` of data, which does not make sense with spans, because a stack-only stream would be of limited use.